# Display multiple images without using <img> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Is there any way I can display 500+ images from a folder on a HTML page without having to write out 500+ img src tags?

I've googled this before coming here, but the only results I can seem to find suggest using PHP, or something called "glob", which I would prefer to try not to use.

Is it possible to use a seperate .js file with the files, then use the script in HTML to display the images?

.jpg and .png files

Comment: If you're not hard coding the images then you'd need something on the server side to read a folder of images and render them to the page. JavaScript alone on the client side can't do that.

Comment: It's entirely possible, and the easiest way to do it depends on the language you wish to use, and the format of the names of the images. You could use a basic PHP loop that goes from 1 to 500 and appends `.png` to each, for example, showing `1.png`, `2.png`, etc. If they're not sequentially-numbered, you'll probably have to use an array with all the filenames.

Comment: Why not just use an each loop to loop though all the images and generate the src dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this (good if they are all in one folder) would be just to loop through the folder. If you want to display them in separate divs you may have to modify the below code.

I have set the number to 75 for demo reasons, you would set it to 500. Or if some are jpg and some are png as you indicated, you could set up a subfolder for each  (jpg and png) and set the var for jpg to e.g 300 and png to 200 etc..

Hope this helps.

```js
var jpgcontainer = document.getElementById('jpg');
var pngcontainer = document.getElementById('png');
var files = {
  'jpg': 300
};

var files2 = {
  'png': 200
};

for (var jpgext in files) {
  for (var i = 0; i < files[jpgext]; i++) {
    var jpgsrc = "images/jpg/" + (i + 1) + "." + jpgext;
    var jpgimg = new Image();
    jpgimg.src = jpgsrc;
    jpgcontainer.appendChild(jpgimg);
  }
}

for (var pngext in files2) {
  for (var j = 0; j < files2[pngext]; j++) {
    var pngsrc = "images/png/" + (j + 1) + "." + pngext;
    var pngimg = new Image();
    pngimg.src = pngsrc;
    pngcontainer.appendChild(pngimg);
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgcontainer">
<section id="jpg">
  
</section>
<section id="png">
  
</section>
</div>
```

[image: jsfiddle screenshot]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/krcs65L5/

Comment: Apologies for the very late response, sadly I couldn't get the images to show using this method :(

Comment: It works if you name your images numerically, 1,2,3... 500 etc

Comment: You'd also have to specify the correct file path..

Comment: Each image is names 1.jpg 2.png etc and the path was correctly specified so I'm unsure. Would the Jquery.min.js need to be used as well?

Comment: I've just imported the jquery file and the images are still not showing :(

Comment: You don't need jQuery

Comment: put the jpgs in a folder and number them 1, 2, 3 etc.. put pngs in a folder, number them 1, 2, 3 etc

Comment: No luck on that method either I'm afraid! It looks like I'm just going to have to use the 500+ img src tags on the HTML page. Thank-you for all your help Rachel, greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/uvs9nw9u/

Comment: if you scroll down and inspect the last image it will say the image is 200.png  in the png section, likewise 300 in the jpg section.. I promise it works! Have used it myself!

Comment: I can see it's working on the fiddle, however I can't seem to get it to work on my side? A daft question, but the path to the images can be altered right? my path is avatars/png/ avatars/jpg/, it doesn't HAVE to be images?

Comment: absolutely, you alter the file path as required, I just set it to images for demo purposes. You should include the whole filepath  (relative to the root on the server)

Comment: Here's a screenshot to show you how I've tried this: https://gyazo.com/31d53e59f8dc2a47158aa265ff079c15 I've only sorted 5 jpg images and 5 pngs out just for testing

Comment: there's an online downloadable tool that batch converts jpg to pngs and vice versa if that would assist you. I think it's called batchIM ... it's pretty good cos it means you can convert lots of image to a certain file type at once

Comment: that screenshot is really hard to read.. and it's not evident what is in the folders and what is not

Comment: In the folders, 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg 4.jpg 5.jpg and same for the png folder, only sorted them 5 for each just to test the code you've provided me, if you click the image on gyazo, it will make it bigger so you can read it

Comment: but where's the html output? all i see is the code.. and the images in the pc.. it doesn't show if it worked or not.. it should work but if you're only using 5 for test it may be wise to set both jpg and png to 5

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that! https://gyazo.com/c239e67d6d24607e5a01c1682f5c64a0

Comment: do you even have these images hosted? like i say set the numbers to 5 in jpg and png or else you'll get errors in the console. I can't see any source there indicating image numbers

Comment: I have the images on my server, yes, but this is being used locally using Brackets live window. Does this only work if on a server or something?

Comment: your section seems to have 2 ids, a data-brackets id and the assigned id. I am not familiar with data brackets but the first id will probably override the  2nd id. Try just using a div instead of a section, and/or using important. Generally speaking better to test on a non-visible test page on the server

Comment: make a copy of your page by using save as.. and save it as test.html or something and upload it to your server. let me know how you go. Its 23:35 my time. Sleep required!

Comment: One last thing, copy code directly from fiddle, it's possible I posted code with a small error on SO. Night night!

Comment: Code on SO is fine. Check your js path or include in script tags. Definitely advise using div id = jpg etc.. your divs don't seem to have extra data wrapper IDs added. No need to adjust your getElementById , they'll still work. (Can't believe I'm still awake!)

Comment: I've uploaded the files to my server, as you can see(www.freevatars.co.uk) it's still not working when it's live :( The paths to the folder are correct, and the files are named 1 2 3 4 5 etc. I've also tried using the script inside the html page just incase the js file wasn't working, but still nothing with that method

Comment: Did you use divs? If you are still using sections you should include the data wrapper part in the getElementById part as well as jpg but check the source to see what the id of the div is if you used divs

Comment: If it's on a test page what is the url!? I'll have a look.

Comment: [Freevatars](http://www.freevatars.co.uk) This isn't a test page, this is my live website which I've uploaded the files too

Comment: Okay . I'm just eating, will look in 20 mins or so. Better to put on a test page!

Comment: the source looks okay. suggest moving the js to bottom of the body instead of having it in the head. if no joy, remove the outer imgcontainer div. I'll try the page on my own hosting on a subdomain in a bit (after eats)

Comment: now the folders/images just give a 404! did you delete them?

Comment: Yes, I'm moving them to a test server so I can have my website back up and running. At this point, I'm moving towards giving up entirely and just going basic HTML. Thanks for all your time and help Rachel, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://www.rachelgallen.com/freevatars.html javascript at the bottom

Comment: There we go, that's got it! THANK YOU VERY MUCH RACHEL!
Any idea why it doesn't work when the code is in it's own javascript file?

Comment: Hurrah! Persistence pays off! :) Dunno why.. maybe if you load the js file at the bottom instead of in the head it would work also? I didn't try it..

Comment: I'll try it, I'm just glad we've got it working, you're a superstar, thank you again!

Comment: happy i could help :)

Comment: just put it in using external script at the bottom. works

Comment: so the moral of the story is put the javascript at the bottom, not in the head.. :)

Comment: the numbers opposite the jpg and png variables match how many are in the folder; so if you have 263 jpgs and 237 pngs your jpg var should be 263 etc.. so ensure you set them correctly

Comment: Yeah, I've figured that out, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can store the image names in a JavaScript array and use [forEach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp) to list all images like this:

```js
var images = [
  'airplane.png',
  'arctichare.png',
  'baboon.png',
  'barbara.png',
];

var baseUrl = 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/';

container = document.getElementById("imagesContainer");
function createImages(item, index) {
  container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + "<img src=\"" + baseUrl + item + "\"/><br/>";
}
images.forEach(createImages);
```

```html
<div id="imagesContainer"></div>
```

If you want to list them automatically, you'd need a server scripting language like PHP.

Comment: Apologies for the very late response, sadly I couldn't get the images to show using this method :(

Comment: Just fixed my example. Did you get any JavaScript error messages in your browsers console? Otherwise, check if the generated path to the images is fine

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use Excel and CONCAT to dynamically create the code for you.

So if you had column A with all the image locations, you would write something like this in column B.  So assume your A column has "image1.png":

```
=CONCAT("<img src='", A1, "' />")
```

And then you would just apply that to your B column all the way down and copy the HTML.